# Discarding the current state after closing dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a confirmation dialog, like the example provided by [material-ui](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/#confirmation-dialogs). The simple example I provided has three text fields. There will be many more inputs in the actual application. When I change a text field, click the cancel button, and re-open the dialog, the change is there instead of the original value.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I'm pretty sure my issue is because I am managing the state of each input separately instead of modifying `layout`, but `layout` will be much larger with more nesting, so I thought it would be easier to manage the state of each input separately. My goal was to manage the state of each input separately, then update `layout` one time, rather than modifying `layout` every time one of the inputs change.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confirmation-dialog-mui-material-xz3k2n).

Here is the actual code:

*App.js*

```
import ConfirmDialog from "./ConfirmDialog";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ConfirmDialog />
    </div>
  );
}
```

*ConfirmDialog.js*

```
import * as React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

function ConfirmationDialogRaw(props) {
  const { onClose, layout: layoutProp, open, ...other } = props;
  const [layout, setLayout] = React.useState(layoutProp);

  // There are many more inputs elements than the three
  // provided in this example
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState(layout.title.text);
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState(layout.name.first);
  const [lastName, setLastName] = React.useState(layout.name.last);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!open) {
      setLayout(layoutProp);
    }
  }, [layoutProp, open]);

  const handleCancel = () => {
    onClose();
  };

  const handleSave = () => {
    onClose({
      title: {
        text: title
      },
      name: {
        first: firstName,
        last: lastName
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      sx={{ "& .MuiDialog-paper": { width: "80%", maxHeight: 435 } }}
      maxWidth="xs"
      open={open}
      {...other}
    >
      <DialogTitle>Layout</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent dividers>
        <TextField
          margin="dense"
          id="title-label"
          label="Title"
          type="text"
          fullWidth
          variant="standard"
          value={title}
          onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          margin="dense"
          id="first-name-label"
          label="First Name"
          type="text"
          fullWidth
          variant="standard"
          value={firstName}
          onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          margin="dense"
          id="last-name-label"
          label="Last Name"
          type="text"
          fullWidth
          variant="standard"
          value={lastName}
          onChange={(event) => setLastName(event.target.value)}
        />
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button autoFocus onClick={handleCancel}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={handleSave}>Save</Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

ConfirmationDialogRaw.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

const defaultLayout = {
  title: {
    text: "Default title"
  },
  name: {
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe"
  }
};

export default function ConfirmationDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [layout, setLayout] = React.useState(defaultLayout);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (newLayout) => {
    setOpen(false);

    if (newLayout) {
      setLayout(newLayout);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleOpen}>
        Open Dialog
      </Button>
      <ConfirmationDialogRaw
        id="layout-dialog"
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        layout={layout}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to keep the state in an object, say default values and then u can set the state easily with the default values object instead of individual state values....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reset it inside the function handleCancel: like this

```
const handleCancel = () => {
    onClose();
    setTitle(layout.title.text);
    setFirstName(layout.name.first);
    setLastName(layout.name.last);
  };
```

---

the other solution is when you are using the  component, add the key prop, and change it each time the onClose function is executed like:

```
export default function ConfirmationDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [layout, setLayout] = React.useState(defaultLayout);
  const [idToRefresh, setIdToRefresh] = React.useState(0); // NEW LINE

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = (newLayout) => {
    setOpen(false);
    setIdToRefresh(idToRefresh + 1); // NEW LINE
    if (newLayout) {
      setLayout(newLayout);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleOpen}>
        Open Dialog
      </Button>
      <ConfirmationDialogRaw
        key={`myConfirmationDialog_v_${idToRefresh}`} {/* NEW LINE */}
        id="layout-dialog"
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        layout={layout}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

With this your component will be generated again and will have all the states again as it was initialized.

You can use `open` too:

```
...
key={`myConfirmationDialog_v_${open}`}
...
```

Comment: I didn’t do that because there will be 20+ states that I would have to include. I was hoping there was a cleaning solution.

Comment: ok, see the other solution and letme know is this works for you. @Simon1

Comment: I went with your last suggestion, using ``open`` in the ``key`` prop and it works perfectly. Thank you!